# the time and space complexity of this permutation algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, permutation

I have written this permutation algorithm.
Could you help me understand it's Time and Space Complexity.

```
public static List<String> permutation(String str) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    if (str.length() == 1) {
        result.add(str);
        return result;
    } else {
        for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
            List<String> subPermList = permutation(str.replace(c + "", ""));
            for (String substr : subPermList) {
                result.add(c + substr);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: How many permutations are generated? Worst is `n!` where `n = str.length()` and all characters in `str` are unique. So there is your answer: time = _O(n!)_, space = _O(n*n!)_

Comment: @Andreas Due to the char-string-concatenation we `n!` times cause a creation of a string of length `n`. So we're at least in `O(n*n!)` for time complexity. After evaluation with Substitution Method, I think it is even `O(n²*n!)`, tough.

Answer (score 0):

I will just concentrate on the time complexity in this answer. The first thing is to write down the recurrence relation for `T(n)`:

```
T(n) = n +                           // str.toCharArray()
       n *                           // for (char c ...)
       (
           T(n-1) +                  // permutation(...)
           n +                       // str.replace(...)
           (n-1)! * n                // for (String substr ...)
       )   
     = n*T(n-1) + n*n! + n² + n
```

The solution to this recurrence relation is `Θ(n² * n!)`.

... which is noticeably worse than `Θ(n * n!)`, which you get in optimal implementations for producing a list of all permutations.